# Corona SDK: Having Single and Double Tap Events on One Object

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to have a different amount of force applied to an object when the screen is tapped a different amount of times ( only once and twice ).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
local function moveUp(event)

    if event.numTaps > 1 then
        jumper:applyForce( 0, 250, jumper.x, jumper.y )
    elseif event.numTaps < 1 then
        jumper:applyForce( 0, 0, jumper.x, jumper.y )
    else
        jumper:applyForce( 0, 200, jumper.x, jumper.y )
    end

end


-- start game

createPlayScreen( )
system.setTapDelay( 2 )
Runtime:addEventListener("tap", moveUp)
```

I've tried moving the `Runtime:addEventListener` into the function. I've also tried have the `event.numTaps == 2` and `event.numTaps == 1`, but to no avail.

The issue is that the *TapDelay* refuses to wait for the second tap.

***Any and all help is greatly appreciated***

*P.S. I have the seconds set to two for testing purposes, but once I find that this works, I will be lowering the time to like 0.3 or something*

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the strategy you are using. For one, it is not scalable (to more than two  taps). But ok, maybe you are 100% sure you will never ever need more than 2 taps. The next problem is that `event.numTaps` can only be 1 or 2, yet your listener tests for < 1! This can never happen. The next problem is that when you tap twice, at least in the simulator (did not test on device) you get two events: one for the first tap with `numTaps = 1`, and another for 2nd tap with `numTaps = 2`. In other words, the Corona engine does not wait before emitting a one-tap event to know if a second tap event occurs within some time range. So you get two tap events for a two-tap event, there is no way of knowing in the handler whether you should "wait" to see if another tap might occur within an allowable delay to constitute a "two-tap" event instead.

What you will have to do is create your own N-tap event generator. Whenever a tap occurs, check if your timer has been started. If so, increase the tap count and reset the timer. If not, start the timer that expires some short delay later. If no other tap occurs in that delay, the count you have saved is your tap number. Reset the counter if your timer expires. I have created some functions that do this and I have put them all in a table "object":

```
local tapEvents = {
    measureInterTapTime = false, -- set to true to measure how fast you can tap!
    onTapHandler = nil, -- set this to your handler

    -- implementation details

    tapTimer = nil,
    tapCounter = 0,
    tapEventTime = 0,

    doneTap = function(self, event)
        self.tapTimer = nil
        if self.onTapHandler then 
            self.onTapHandler(self.tapCounter)
        end
        self.tapCounter = 0
        self.tapEventTime = 0
    end,

    -- end implementation details

    tap = function(self, event)
        self.tapCounter = self.tapCounter + 1
        if self.tapTimer ~= nil then
            timer.cancel(self.tapTimer)
            self.tapTimer = nil
        end
        local delayMS = 250
        self.tapTimer = timer.performWithDelay(delayMS, function(e) self:doneTap(e) end, 1)

        -- check how much time between taps, for interest:
        if self.measureInterTapTime then 
            if self.tapEventTime ~= 0 then 
                local interTapTime = system.getTimer() - self.tapEventTime
                print("Time (ms) between taps:", interTapTime)
            end
            self.tapEventTime = system.getTimer()
        end
    end,
}

tapEvents.onTapHandler = function(tapCounter)
    print(tapCounter .. "-tap event")
end

-- because tapEvents contains a 'tap' function, will get called automatically with self:
Runtime:addEventListener('tap', tapEvents)
```

This captures N-tap events without limit!! I have included a flag you can set to true if you want to print out the ms delay between single taps so you can determine what the optimum delay should be (you don't want delay to be too short or you might inadvertently break an N tap into two smaller events; you don't want it to be too long either, or user will have to noticeably wait to indicate "end of my multitap").

Answer (score -1):

Tap events must be added to a display object, not to the Runtime.

If you have a display object jumper for example, use:

```
jumper:addEventListener("tap", moveUp)
```

More documentation here: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/tap/index.html

Comment: Well the single event works on runtime  and the double tap works when its all alone... what if i had a single tap and a timed touch?

Comment: This is not necessary. Tap event can be anywhere on screen via the Runtime.